# Delete the top row of a table in Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I go about deleteing the first row of a table in SQL on Acess 2007? I've tried Delete Top (1), but this causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need:

```
DELETE t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.ID In (SELECT Top 1 ID FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from tableName where IDCOLUMN = 
(
 select top(1) IDCOLUMN from tableName
)
```

Comment: For MS Access, you need to drop the brackets (1) and add an ORDER BY.